# would monetdb work faster with boolean or varchar(1) data types?

Tags: monetdb

Would a query run faster in a column defined as boolean or as varchar(1) in monetdb ?

queries would look like:

with varchar(1)

`select * from many_many_rows where has_fancy_value = 'T'`

with boolean

`select * from many_many_rows where has_fancy_value = true`

Is there any difference performance wise

Answer (score 4):

It should not make a difference.

Since MonetDB dictionary-compresses strings, only pointers into the dictionary are stored. When scan-selecting on a string-column and the dictionary is small it will first scan the dictionary to get the pointer for the value and than scan the table using that pointer. If the dictionary is small enough, it will use a single byte as pointer (or pointer offset). Since a boolean is also stored as a byte and the overhead for the dictionary can be neglected, it should not make a difference.

I'd strongly suggest to use boolean nevertheless, because

a) it avoids that people put other strings than 'T' and 'F' in,

b) you avoid confusion about the case: 'T' vs. 't' and

c) one day, Monet might support smaller than byte datatypes (plans for that exist so it might actually happen... or not :-)).

Comment: I second @Holger on using boolean. I agree about the dictionary-compressed strings, but there is one more reason to use boolean: many of MonetDB's internal operators are optimized for fixed-size data types and fall back into more generic algorithms for variable size data types (like strings).